# useNavigate don't work with HOC Component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, node.js, express, react-router-dom

This is my first question.
I am self-studying React.js, Node.js, and Express. For this reason, I am trying to create my own website where a user can register, log in, and access the page with their data only if the login is successful.

If the login is successful, a token is created using the user's email as the payload. Additionally, I want to use a Higher Order Component (HOC)

**Protect.js**

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { Navigate } from 'react-router-dom';
import axios from 'axios';

const Protect = ({ component: Component }) => {
  const [authenticated, setAuthenticated] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    
    const checkAuth = async () => {
      try {
        
        const response = await axios.get('http://localhost:5000/checkAuth', { withCredentials: true });
        console.log('Protected GET Response:', response.data);
        
        if (response.status === 200) {
          setAuthenticated(true);
        } else {
          setAuthenticated(false);
        }
      } catch (error) {
        console.error('Protect: Error during auth', error.response);
        setAuthenticated(false);
      }
    };


    checkAuth();
  }, []);

return authenticated ? <Component /> : <Navigate to="/Login" />;

};

export default Protect;
```

so that in my `App.js` file, I have something like:

```js
<Route
    path="/ProtectedPage"
    element={<Protect component={<ProtectedPage />} />}
/>
```

In the `handleFormSubmit` function of `FormLogin`, I added

```js
      const handleFormSubmit = async (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
  
    const formData = {
      email: email,
      password: password,
    };
  
    try {
      const response = await axios.post('http://localhost:5000/login', formData, { withCredentials: true });
      console.log("Client: Server Says: ", response.data);
      console.log("Client:  Login OK");
  
      navigate('/ProtectedPage');
    } catch (error) {
      console.log('Server Error:', error);
    }
  };
```

It might be useful to know that `Protected` makes a GET request to

```js
const verifyToken = (req, res, next) => {
  const token = req.cookies.token;

  if (!token) {
    res.status(401).send('Access Denied');
  } else {
    jwt.verify(token, secret, function (err, decoded) {
      if (err) {
        res.status(401).send('No Valid Token!');
      } else {
        req.email = decoded.email;
        req.token = token;
        console.log('verifyToken: ', req.email);
        next();
      }
    });
  }
};

app.get('/checkAuth', verifyToken, (req, res) => {
    res.sendStatus(200).send({ authenticated: true, email: req.email, token: req.token});
});
```

You can view my code at this link: https://github.com/CiccioLagXCVIII/MyOwnSite.git

But even if the login is successful, I don't get any errors or redirection to `/ProtectedPage`

Thanks to anyone who will respond.

I have already tried using `console.log` to verify if the data is received and sent correctly, and it is. My issue is that I don't see any errors (I only see the logs that I have entered myself for debugging)  in the console when the login is successful, but the redirection doesn't happen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First just a clarification on nomenclature: `Protect` isn't a Higher Order Component, e.g. it's not a function that takes a React component as an argument and returns a *decorated* React component, it is just a regular React component that takes a `component` prop.

The issue is that `Protect` uses an initial `authenticated` value that matches  unauthenticated users and on the initial render will redirect users to the `"/login"` route.

Start from an "unknown" authentication state and wait for the `checkAuth` code to complete and update the `authenticated` state prior to rendering the protected content or redirecting.

The `component` prop is already JSX, as passed from `component={<PaginaProtetta />}` in the `Route`, so `Protect` should simply return `component` or the redirect.

Example:

```
const Protect = ({ component }) => {
  const [authenticated, setAuthenticated] = useState(); // <-- initially undefined

  useEffect(() => {
    const checkAuth = async () => {
      try {
        const response = await axios.get(
          'http://localhost:5000/checkAuth',
          { withCredentials: true }
        );
        setAuthenticated(response.status === 200);
      } catch (error) {
        setAuthenticated(false);
      }
    };

    checkAuth();
  }, []);

  if (authenticated === undefined) {
    return null; // <-- or loading indicator/spinner/etc
  }

  return authenticated ? component : <Navigate to="/Login" replace />;
};
```

```
const App = () => {
  return (
    <Router>
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/Login" element={<FormLogin />} />
        <Route
          path="/ProtectedPage"
          element={<Protect component={<PaginaProtetta />} />}
        />
      </Routes>
    </Router>
  );
};
```

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. 
Now I understand better, and I have modified my code. However, I still have the same issue, namely that even if ```authenticated``` becomes ```true``` the line

```return authenticated ? <Component /> : <Navigate to="/Login" replace />```
doesn't work, and it doesn't go to the /ProtectedPage address.

Comment: @FrancescoLoVerde I see. It's because the `component` prop is already JSX, e.g. `<Route path="/ProtectedPage" element={<Protect component={<PaginaProtetta />} />} />`, the return should be `return authenticated ? component : <Navigate to="/Login" replace />;`. I'll update answer.

Comment: @FrancescoLoVerde And just FYI, if you are interested in a more conventional route protection implementation you can check one of my answers [here](/a/66289280/8690857).

Answer (score 0):

i think you have imported useNavigate hook, if not must import. and if don't work you can try this.

```js
import React from 'react';
import { Navigate, useLocation } from "react-router-dom"
import { useSelector } from 'react-redux';
import { selectAuthState } from './redux/features/auth/authSlice';

const PrivateRoute = ({ children }) => {
    const isAuthenticated = useSelector(selectAuthState);
    let location = useLocation();

    if (!isAuthenticated) {
        return <Navigate to="/login" state={{ from: location }} replace />
    }

    return children;
};

export default PrivateRoute;
```